# C#, MDI и его процесс загрузки

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть родительская форма EditData, и дочерняя форма DataClass. Как только открываю дочернюю форму там идет выгрузка данные с MS SQL в DataGridView, очень долго загружается. И я решил, добавить дополнительную форму Process, чтоб пользователю было понятнее, что она загружается дочерняя форма. И как только загрузилась (т.е. открылась) дочерняя форма, то тогда форма Process закрывается.
Но никак не получается...

Вот пример кода, родительская форма EditData:

```
Process process; 
public EditData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void OpenClassificationWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataClass == null || dataClass.IsDisposed)
            {
                process = new Process();
                process.ShowDialog();
                dataClass = new DataClass(process)
                {
                    MdiParent = this
                };
                dataClass.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                dataClass.Activate();
            }
        }
```

Пример кода, дочерняя форма DataClass:

```
    string connection = Settings.Default.DataClient; 
    SqlConnection sqlConnection; 
    SqlCommand sqlCommand; 
    public DataClass(Process pr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadingClass();
        pr.Close();
    }
private void LoadingClass()
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Class";
        sqlConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConnection);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(set);
            TableClass.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();

        }
    }
```

Пример кода, форма загрузки Process:

```
public Process()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task task = Task.Run(() => Work());

    }
    public void Work()
    {
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
    }
```

Но форма загрузки не закрывается, и не открывается дочерняя форма. Если вместо **ShowDialog** поставить на **Show**, то вообще не видно *ProgressBar* и так же самое, не закроется и не откроется дочерняя форма.

**P.S.** Помогите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать процесс? У меня скоро будет защита проекта...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Пример работы]

Вот метод кнопки

```
private async void buttonShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //готовим окно ожидания
        FormWaiting formWaiting = new FormWaiting();
        formWaiting.Owner = this;
        //показываем окно ожидания
        formWaiting.Show();

        try
        {
            //готовим окно данных
            _formData = new FormData();
            _formData.Owner = this;
            //даем команду загрзить данные
            await Task.Run(() => _formData.LoadData());
        }
        finally
        {
            //закрываем окно ожидания
            formWaiting.Close();
            formWaiting.Dispose();

            //отображаем окно с данными
            _formData.Show();
        }
    }
```

Вот форма, которая отображает данные

```
public partial class FormData : Form
{
    private Repository _repo = new Repository();
    private BindingSource _wordsSource = new BindingSource();

    public FormData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        //тестовая пауза
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        //получаем из БД данные
        _wordsSource.DataSource = _repo.GetWords();
        _dataGridViewWords.DataSource = _wordsSource;
    }
}
```

Целиком проект можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/kYO6SFET3XtfkK).